# How to push notifications to iOS with Google Cloud Messaging

Tags: xamarin, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, google-cloud-messaging

We have succesfully managed to send push notifications on Android from GCM, but I was wondering how can I connect to Apple Push Notification Service with GCM? Do I need to download some API´s on the client side or is everything supported on the backend? I am using Xamarin.Forms to develop the frontend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use APNS or 3rd party stuffs like PushSharp

Please have a look at the following threads. There is a bit of configuring required to have push notifications enabled in Ios. You need a couple of certificates.

http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/notifications/ios/remote_notifications_in_ios/

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/20845/how-to-approach-push-notifications-on-xamarin-forms-project

Answer (score 1):

Google recently launched GCM for iOS. There is a Objective-C API available, however, I'm unsure if there is a Xamarin wrapper in place anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Xamarin has finally published the free component [Google Cloud Messaging for iOS](https://components.xamarin.com/view/googleiosgcm)

And [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Google.iOS.GoogleCloudMessaging/) is a link to nuget package.